ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'
I know this topic has been asked multiple times but I cannot seem to find a solution that works form.
I'm running a streamlit application through a virtual environment (.venv).
Python version: Python 3.11.5
Interpreter: VS Code
I'm running on MacBook
I have my requirements.txt file and calling the following libraries related to "snowflake":
snowflake==0.11.0
snowflake-snowpark-python==1.20.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.1
snowflake._legacy==0.11.0
snowflake.core==0.11.0

I get an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'.
The funny thing is that if I just call
python3 -c "import snowflake.connector" in the terminal it does NOT return an issue. Also - my college is executing the same app in an venv and he does not get an error.
Any suggestions?

This can be a problem where you installed packages on global python installation instead of your virtual environment

Hm... That can be it but I checked the "lib" folder into .venv and I see the packages. Also, I do the installation after I have sourced the .venv. Maybe I'm missing sth (not that experienced in python, honestly). Maybe I need to change sth in the PYTHONPATH but in the .venv?

Ok,
After a couple of hours pointless struggling I realised that while my python  environment is correctly related to the .venv (which python) my streamlit is still pointing to my base environment (in my case anaconda).
What solved is you can:

either run your application through a normal terminal outside of VS Code
or you can use python3 -m streamlit run.app so that you reroute streamlit to the proper environment prior launch.

Looks like you never now your under which environment is your VS Code operating under... go figure!
